# FIFO communication issue [Fixed]

Tags: c, linux, process, fifo

I'm practicing linux fifo reading and writing. I created two files. One is client.c, and another is server.c. I'm trying to swap the name of the two program. So I created two fifo. client first writes in AToB fifo, pending server to read. And then client waits for the server to write in BToA fifo.

Why both of the program didn't proceed to the end, and it seems both of them are waiting each other?

My result is as follows:

[image]

client.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>


int main(int argc, char** argv)
{

    char name[80];
    char temp[80];


    strcpy(name,"Harris");
    name[strlen(name)]='\0';

    printf("Original name: %s\n",name);


    char * myfifo = "AToB";
    char * myfifo2 = "BToA";

    mkfifo(myfifo, 0666);
    mkfifo(myfifo2, 0666);
    /////////////////////////////////////////////


    int fd = open(myfifo, O_WRONLY);
    int fd2 = open(myfifo2, O_RDONLY);
    //////////////////////////////////////

    write(fd, name, strlen(name)+1);
    close(fd);
    read(fd2, temp, sizeof(temp));
    close(fd2);


    strcpy(name,temp);

    name[strlen(name)]='\0';

    printf("After name: %s\n",name);




    return 0;
}
```

server.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{

    char name[80];
    char temp[80];

    strcpy(name,"Amy");


    printf("Original name: %s\n",name);



    char * myfifo = "AToB";
    char * myfifo2 = "BToA";


    int fd = open(myfifo2, O_WRONLY);
    int fd2 = open(myfifo, O_RDONLY);




    ////////////////////////////////////////



    read(fd2, temp, sizeof(temp));

    close(fd2);

    write(fd, name, strlen(name)+1);
    close(fd);

    strcpy(name,temp);

    name[strlen(name)]='\0';

    printf("After name: %s\n",name);




    return 0;
}
```

Updated:
I fixed the problem myself. It seems that I cannot open multiple fifo at once. If I modify the code like the following, it will work.

```
 int fd = open(myfifo, O_WRONLY);
 write(fd, name, strlen(name)+1);
 close(fd);
 
 int fd2 = open(myfifo2, O_RDONLY);
 read(fd2, temp, sizeof(temp));
 close(fd2);
```

Comment: Client is waiting for the read end of AToB to be opened and server is waiting for the read end of BToA to be opened. Deadlock.

Comment: @Shawn But shouldn't it be for both of the program proceed to the BToA fifo after completing the AToB data transfer? because I thought FIFO is blocking. So Only after they both read and write the AToB fifo will they proceed to BToA?

Comment: You should make your update into an answer. You can then accept it. You'll get more reps that way

Comment: No. Opening a fifo blocks until something else opens the other end. Your programs never get past their first `open()`.

Answer (score 1):

Updated:
I fixed the problem myself. It seems that I cannot open multiple fifo at once. If I modify the code like the following, it will work.

```
 int fd = open(myfifo, O_WRONLY);
 write(fd, name, strlen(name)+1);
 close(fd);
 
 int fd2 = open(myfifo2, O_RDONLY);
 read(fd2, temp, sizeof(temp));
 close(fd2);
```